# Error in R long vectors not supported yet

Tags: r, model.matrix, e1071

I am using  CentOS 7 Linux compute cluster, with 130 GB RAM. I am trying to use the SVM function from the e1071 R package. My matrix dimension is rows = 350 and columns = 54250.

R script Code (file_testR.R)

```
matris=matrix(rnorm(100),350,54251)
matris <- as.data.frame(matris)
matris$new_variable <- 0
matris$new_variable[1:175] <- "yes"
matris$new_variable[176:350] <- "no"
require(e1071)
svmfit_test <- svm(as.factor(matris$new_variable)~., data = matris, kernel = "linear", cross=10)
```

Bash code

```
Rscript --max-ppsize=500000 file_testR.R
```

I am getting this below error:

```
Error in model.matrix.default(Terms, m) : 
  long vectors not supported yet: ../../src/include/Rinlinedfuns.h:522
Calls: svm ... svm.formula -> model.matrix -> model.matrix.default
```

I would appreciate it if anybody could help me to understand this issue.

Comment: Please edit the question with minimal code to reproduce the error.

Comment: I'm running this on MacOS with the slight modification that I started with `nc <- 54251; nr <- 350; matris <- matrix(rnorm(nc*nr), ncol=nc)` (your code doesn't quite work). It's taking a while but doesn't seem to be having any long-vector problems. (I didn't run it in Rscript, just in an interactive session.)

Comment: ... but eventually got a "protection stack overflow", so I'll have to work on your example some more.

Comment: I got the "protection stack overflow" error on my computer with 36GB RAM. But after moving to HPC I got only the following error, " model.matrix.default(Terms, m) ...."